# How to modify the live cd image to make it writeable

Tags: debian, live-usb

What to add to Debian live CDs (like here: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/) to make them writeable? I want to configure them for the school lab for running PICO-8 fantasy consoles with cartridges being kept and updated on the board.

I see that we can use the command:

> sudo mount -o remount,rw

But is it appliable to the "filesystem.squashfs" file in the "live" folder?

Comment: Must it be optical media (CD or DVD disk), or could you also distribute an image file? There are several options with image files, to run in a VM as already described by Marcus Müller or booted from a USB pendrive (as persistent live or installed system).

Answer (score 2):

You can't make squashfs writeable – a squashfs file system cannot be changed (it can be appended to, but you usually do not want that).

The right approach here is learning how Debian customizes their own CDs and just do your own. (Another option is to install debian to disk on a VM instead, modify the disk installation, and then just distribute the resulting VM image for each student to run on their computer.)

How to build your own, customized, debian liveCD is documented [here](https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/). [Tutorial 2](https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/examples.en.html#tutorial-2) shows how to add packages to your image